# Is there an advantage to using References instead of Strings with _ids in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We're building an API and deciding between doing references like this:

```
var postSchema = Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

or just using a `String` with the `_id`:

```
var postSchema = Schema({
  user: { type: String }
});
```

Is there any benefit to doing it either way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose schemas has nothing to do with MongoDB inner workings. It's based on preference, if you use this:

```
var postSchema = Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

Mongoose will give you some advantages over the other solution. [Population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) is one of them.

Comment: interesting, so the underlying implementation is the same? Also, it's not an opinion based question, I'm asking if there's a benefit

Comment: as long as MongoDB is concerned nothing is different, but there is a benefit with mongoose if you choose to use it

Comment: Would be happy to once you remove the first sentence of it

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose provide a mechanism to query the ref Object in response if Schema defined as mentioned below

```
var postSchema = Schema({
  title: {type: String}
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});
```

Then Query will be like

```
Post.
  findOne({ title: "Let's learn" }).
  populate('user').
  exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    // your post with user details
  });
```

This is one usecase,
checkout this documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html for more detailed description and usecases about ref.